# Problem in reading specific column of a file using pandas and readlines()

Tags: python-3.x

I have .csv file with the following headers:

created_time,from_id,from_name,message,post_id

I want to retrieve text under the 'message' header. The problem I am facing is that if I use 'pandas' and write to file 'b.txt' then the number of rows in b.txt exceeds the number of rows in the original file. If I use readlines() then  an error message as 'Index out of range' is flashed on the output screen

The last problem is avoiding blank lines present in the original file to be written in the b.txt file

The original file has emojis and text, for example, "told you it would happen soon".

Here is the code, I am trying using 'pandas':

```
df = pd.read_csv('original.csv')
outfile=open('b.txt','w', encoding='utf-8')

for i, ir in df.iterrows():
    text = uni_emoji(str(ir['message'])) // to convert emoji to unicode
    if text !='': //to avoid blank line to be written in 'b.txt' 
        outfile.write(text)
        outfile.write('\n')
```

The code, I am trying using 'readlines()':

```
infile=open('original.csv','r', encoding='utf-8')
outfile=open('b.txt','w', encoding='utf-8')
for line in infile.readlines():
    text = line.split(' ')[3])
    text = uni_emoji(str(text)) // to convert emoji to unicode
    if text !='': //to avoid blank line to be written in 'b.txt' 
        outfile.write(text)
        outfile.write('\n')
```

Could not understand why rows in b.txt exceed than the original file and second, index out of range error using readlines().

Few lines from .csv files is as follows:

2017-07-14T14:48:45+0000,792550924247692,Anna Waas,"For the ones who claim guns save lives, can you find the data that number of lives saved is more than 40105 lives annually?""All shootings: Some 13,286 people were killed in the US by firearms in 2015, according to the Gun Violence Archive, and 26,819 people were injured"" http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-34996604",228735667216_10154890879532217

2017-07-14T15:00:59+0000,1961056330586634,Eileen Christiano Dixon,"Unless a person practices religiously with their firearm, I think in most cases it would be useless...

And I don't believe the majority of gun owners have done that... getting certified, going to the firing range does not make one competent or confident to own a firearm..if you own, commit to it, otherwise forget it",228735667216_10154890879532217

2017-07-14T15:00:07+0000,1476468122376547,Sulph Moses,"All they care about is profit, the could careless about the lives been lost, its possible the rights to guns is a law from a primitive time that needs to be changed..",228735667216_10154890879532217

2017-07-14T14:23:10+0000,145642302680166,Sarah Gray,"People are turning into animals if not worse.

Why can't we all live in peace and love each other? Hope the family are ok ",228735667216_10154890968202217

2017-07-14T14:36:26+0000,10214018177317275,Amy Brown,Neil Hank is this enough for them to change the travel status to Hurghada?? ,228735667216_10154890968202217

Comment: could it be that value of text itself has a newline character so newline is written twice_

Comment: could you post a few lines of the original csv file to get a better idea of how the data looks like

Comment: Edited my question to incorporate sample from the .csv file